# QGIS 3.0.0. Coordinate display incorrect

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

My CRS is reported by QGIS (project properties) as being ED50/UTM31N (EPSG 23031) and that seems to be correct as all layers are positioned correctly. However, the coordinate display box shows the latitude and longitude (in degrees) as being the same. When the coordinate display is set to "map units(meters)" it displays correctly.

[image]    [image]

Is this to do with the fact that on-the-fly transformations no longer appear to be available in 3.0.0?

Comment: On the fly projection is ALWAYS enabled in 3.0

Comment: Thought that might be the case, but my coordinate display problem remains. QGIS 2.18.16 behaves itself in this respect.

Comment: Ha - you found a bug. I'll fix for 3.0.1

Comment: Excellent! I was beginning to think it was something I'm doing incorrectly. Thanks. When is 3.0.1 due? (I'm generally liking 3.0.0 btw....)

Comment: A couple of days - there's a timer on the qgis homepage

Comment: @ndawson please post an answer so this can be marked as solved

Answer (score 2):

Just now tested this issue with QGIS 3.2 - all works fine, perhaps this bug is fixed.